# Why do yekkes say Shir Mizmor Le'Osof each morning?

Tags: minhag, tehilim-psalms, ashkenazi, nusach-ashkenaz, yekke

There is a very old Minhag Ashkenaz (i.e. practiced by yekkes) that every day after Shacharis (or Musaf) one says [Psalm 83](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.83?lang=bi) (Shir Mizmor LeOsof).

I have done this for a long time, however I am yet to find a reason behind this. So, what is the reason for this minhag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the siddur *Sefas Yisroel* from [OpenSiddur](http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Tefiloh-Sefas-Yisroel-1-Shacharit.pdf) it is written:

> שיר מזמור לאסף  has been recited since the end of the Geonic period - a few hundred years before the introduction of the  שיר של יום. Its first appearance in אשכנז was in the [מחזור ויטרי](http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=add_ms_27200_f042v),* most likely as a result of the צרות and גזירות that were imposed upon עם ישראל at the time.

And indeed it is mentioned by [Emden](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19725&st=&pgnum=384) and [Heidenheim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19723&st=&pgnum=84), and recited in Ungarn-Böhmen-Mähren communities as well (see this [Anton Schmid](https://books.google.it/books?id=jSViAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT114) or any Schlesinger siddur ad loc.) with a comment that it is not read on days, when Tachanun is omitted except for Chanuka and Purim. This theory is further confirmed by the fact that the book *The Aleppo Codex* by Matti Friedman reports (p. 37.) that this psalm was recited, when the Arabs attacked the Jews in Aleppo.

<sub>* However, it should be noted that instead of the last two verses ([18-19](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2683.htm#18)) it continues with Yeshayahu [8:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1008.htm#10), Psalm [5:11-12](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2605.htm#11), [40:17](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2640.htm#17) and so on.</sub>